# Cells temporarily disappearing when TableView beginUpdates / endUpdates

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I am trying to make a expandable table view **(static cells)**. A container view is placed inside a cell below the "Lists of options" cell, as shown below: [image]

The problem comes with the animation when expanding / collapsing. The topmost cell of each section will disappear briefly(hidden?), then reappear after the animation ends. I have later experimented and the results are as followed:

This will not happen when using **`tableView.reloadData()`**.

This will happen when using **`tableView.beginUpdates() / endUpdates()`** pairs.

Hence I have come to the conclusion that this has sth to do with the animation. Below is my code and pictures for further explanation for said issue.

**Code for hiding / showing**

```
private func hideContainerView(targetView: UIView) {
    if targetView == violationOptionsContainerView {
        violationOptionContainerViewVisible = false
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates() 

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { targetView.alpha = 0.0 }) { _ in
        targetView.isHidden = true
   }
}

private func showContainerView(targetView: UIView) {
    if targetView == violationOptionsContainerView {
        violationOptionContainerViewVisible = true
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    targetView.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { targetView.alpha = 1.0 }) { _ in
        targetView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

**Table view**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        switch cell {
        case violationTableViewCell:
            if violationOptionContainerViewVisible {
                hideContainerView(targetView: violationOptionsContainerView)
            } else {
                showContainerView(targetView: violationOptionsContainerView)
            }
        default: break
        }
        // tableView.reloadData()
        // if we use this instead of begin/end updates, the cells won't disappear. But then we'll be ditching animation too.     
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 3 {
        if !violationOptionContainerViewVisible {
            return 0.0
        }
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

**Images**

[image]

*Note that the first cell in each section ("FFFF" and the "slider bar") disappears and reappears during the animation*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a few days, I have found the cause to this behavior.

I have, for some reason, set the cells `layer.zposition` below default zero. This will cause the cell to be seen "below" it's background view (hence disappeared) during the animation even though it's a subview of it.

Adjusting the value back to 0 or higher will remove this issue.